# Eureka: life cycle of registered service instances

Tags: spring-boot, jboss, netflix-eureka

I am trying to deploy a couple of Spring Boot based microservices on a JBoss EAP. My overall application contains Eureka server and several microservices that should register themselves to the service registry.

While there were some minor issues, we have managed to deploy these services to the JBoss server, but there is an issue with service registration.

Eureka clients fail to register themselves, at least partially. They get registered, but they get stuck in status **Starting**. When I check the heartbeats - they are executed all the time.

I wonder what is the lifecycle of Eureka service registrations and what kind of events move them from one to another.

Or, to be more concrete, I wonder what should I do to have my services registered in the state **UP**, so that it can be consumed by other services?

Answer (score 1):

I have learned different things while trying to find a solution to this problem.

First of all, possible statuses of the registered client instances are STARTING, UP, DOWN, OUT OF SERVICE and UNKNOWN. The purpose of the STARTING state is actually to prevent an application that is still starting up to receive requests it is not yet ready to process.

All communication between the services and the service registry take place via simple REST API described here: https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Eureka-REST-operations.

Once registered at the Eureka server, the service state will remain the same, as long as heartbeat requests are executed.

If you enable **eureka.client.healthcheck.enabled=true**, the health of the application will be propagated to the Eureka server and server state will reflect the health status of the application.

However, when you deploy your Spring Boot application in Jboss server, due to some reasons that are still unknown to me, the autoconfiguration performs different compared to standalone Spring Boot application deployment.

We have finally fixed the problem by setting **eureka.instance.instance-enabled-onit: true** in our application.yml.

This purpose of this property, that is not documented and seems to be misspelled (instance-enabled-on-init?) is to immediately register your application as UP, even though the default initial state is STARTING.